# C# How is it possible for this variable to NOT call its constructor when I create my object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

A variable (myCharacterData) fails to construct itself properly, and I don't understand how that is possible.

I call my instantiation method like this,

```
PlayerScript newPlayer = CustomInstantiatePlayerChar() as PlayerScript;
//newPlayer.myCharacterData = new CharacterData(); //REQUIRED
```

And it creates a new gameobject with the correct component (PlayerScript) attached. However, the variable inside PlayerScript is never initialized. I have to initialize it myself (commented out line "//REQUIRED")

However when I go to my PlayerScript class,

```
public class PlayerScript
{
    public CharacterData myCharacterData = new CharacterData();
```

...

```
 int a;
 string b;
 public CharacterData()
    {
        a = 3;
        b = "fizz";
    }
```

Whenever any PlayerScript object is created, shouldn't its myCharacterData always result in *a = 3, b = "fizz"?*

Is there a possibility that you could create a PlayerScript with the myCharacterData resulting in *null or a=0, string = ""?*

**Doesn't declaring myCharacterData this way insure that anytime I create a PlayerScript object, a=3 & b = "fizz"? That it will always call its constructor?"**

```
public CharacterData myCharacterData = new CharacterData();
```

I am confused because if I don't include the commented out line, then the result is a = 0 & b = "". As if it doesn't matter if I write it as

```
public CharacterData myCharacterData = new CharacterData();
```

or

```
public CharacterData myCharacterData;
```

or

```
public CharacterData myCharacterData = null;
```

As they will always result in a = 0, b = "". Even though the first code snippet calls new CharacterData().

Comment: Although it is a dangerous assumption, I don't really see why CustomInstantiatePlayerChar() would go out of its way to make sure myCharacterData never calls its constructor, since it would have to create a new PlayerScript object (which would call myCharacterData constructor).

Comment: Please show the definition of `CustomInstantiatePlayerChar()`

Comment: You should provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know Unity terribly well, however I do know that in many situations Unity will serialize and deserialize your objects.

When Unity is deserializing your `CharacterData` it will not call the constructor so the private fields will not be initialized. By default Unity does not serialize/deserialize private fields (e.g. a and b). If you wish your a and b private fields to be serialized you may add the `[SerializeField]` attribute to both fields or make both fields public, e.g.:

```
[SerializeField]
int a;
[SerializeField]
string b;
```

or

```
public int a;
public string b;
```

This is documented at [Serialization in Unity](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/06/24/serialization-in-unity/) and [Unity Script Reference: Serialize Field](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html).